# How can i add event to mouse-in mouse out for dynamic DOM element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I manage mouse-over and mouse-out for DOM elements,

```
$(".selector").hover(function(){
    console.log('in');
},function(){
    console.log('out');
});
```

But it doesn't work for dynamic content, how can i do same for dynamic elements.

Comment: dynamic elements means you are getting them by ajax or something like that??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: no am using plugin, which create elements from json object, in hidden field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `.on()` method. Nnote that `hover` is a shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and not `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

Also, performance-wise, it would be better to select a closing static parent element instead of the `document` object.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
       console.log('in');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       console.log('out');
    }
}, '.selector');
```

Comment: I never knew that syntax existed

Comment: @KevinBowersox it is in the DOC, the second sig: `events
Type: PlainObject` But missing example in DOC :(

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually there is an example, search for `Attach multiple event handlers simultaneously using a plain object.`  To bad we couldn't hyperlink to it.

Comment: @KevinBowersox damn i missed it ;)

Comment: it work fine but on Mozilla Firefox mouseenter is not triggerd at all :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".selector", function(){
   //code here
});

$(document).on("mouseenter", ".selector", function(){
   //code here
});
```

The `on` function will attach an event handler that listens for the specified event (first argument) on the selected object.  When the event is fired and bubbles to the selected element (document in our case), it checks if the target element matches the second argument (the selector).  If the target matches the function supplied is fired.  In my example I select `document` however you should select the closest non dynamic parent available for better performance.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(".selector").mouseover(function(){
    console.log('in');
});

$(".selector").mouseleave(function(){
    console.log('in');
});
```

Comment: The OP asked about elements dynamically placed on the DOM are you sure this will work?

Comment: **HINT** Dynamically placed

Comment: Here is what I'm getting at.  If the elements already exist on the `DOM` your code will work fine.  But if they don't exist the event handler will not be fired because the event does not get attached.  That is where `on` comes in.  When `on` is used with a selector specified, the event handler will be attached to elements added to the `DOM`, for instance with jQuery's `append` method.  My code handles that scenario because it uses `on`, the code you have posted will not handle `dynamic` html elements.  If your familiar with the `live` function (don't use) its the same principle.